# Прыгают вкладки в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Недавно начала происходить магия: после отладки открытые вкладки с кодом начинают сами перепрыгивать на другие позиции в ленте.

Заметил закономерность: на каком участке кода остановил отладку - та вкладка и прыгнет на первое место. Остальные, наверное, в хронологическом порядке выполнения

Как это исправить?

Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Productivity Power Tools стоит?

Comment: @АндрейNOP предполагаю, что это какой-то плагин. Нет, плагины не ставил

Comment: Попробуйте в настройках по ключевым словам поискать: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yacad.png